# unable to install any software or package

Tags: 12.04, installation, software-center, package-management

I am recently shifted to ubuntu from windows and i installed ubuntu 12.04 32 bit i am unbale to install any packages like **google talk plugins, teamviewer** it flash a message "**package operation failed**" and while installing **Skype** it shows the message "**Dependency is not satisfiable skype bin**".

after trying lot with google unable to get any useful answer.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple reasons for that. 
Here are some things you can try:

In a Terminal type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
```

then these :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally If none of those get rid of it. 
I would do this:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

when install go to synaptic and click on edit then fix broken packages.
I would like to suggest synaptic for package management anyway.

Let me know how that works out.

For more information [Click Here.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1986644)

Comment: thank you for your answer but, its now working for me any other suggestion please

Comment: When you try this what errors do you get?  Just saying it doesn't work does not help much but if you tell us specifically what the errors are we may be able to help.  Edit your original question to include what you have tried and the reported errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a crude answer but it works.  Print a list of your installed programs, things you've installed, not a full package list. Backup your /home/ and reinstall.

**Edit**

To get a list of installed packages

```
dpkg --get-selections > installed-software
```

This creates a file **installed-software** listing the software installed on your computer.  You can compare that with the list of files installed by default to find what has been added if you want.

Any version of Ubuntu has a manifest , where all the default pre-installed packages listed.

For 12.04 LTS this list is here => http://nl.releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Scroll down the page and you will see a file ends with .manifest

Depends on what version of Ubuntu have installed (i386=32bit or amd64=64bit) download the manifest and open it with Libreoffice to read it.

Comment: what is the command to do print the list of installed program and for backup??